# How to handle restful API calls with null JSON response?

Tags: rest, for-loop, python-requests, null, jsonresponse

Using the requests package, I'm looking to loop through API calls, return JSON responses, and append the responses to a list. The for loop is failing because some of the responses are returning NULL responses. How can I skip past the NULL responses in my for loop? I'm getting the following error:

`requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

I've tried changing the response property from .json to .text as a workaround, but I get the following error:

`str' object is not callable`

The for loop:

```
Cfinancials_all = []
for i in companyfinancials_links:
ddr = requests.get(i, headers=headers, data=payload)
    print(ddr.json())
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example where it works and one where it does not work? Kinda hard to give the correct answer without seeing the data.